# Unexpected behavior when have return statment in If condition

Tags: java, android, debugging, if-statement, return

I have a method, to test a string,

```
  public boolean teste()
    {
        if ( "com.br".equals("com.br") ) {
            //String teste = "1";
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

This method always return false, when debuging, the debugger says that it will never pass in the `return true;` line!
IF I uncomment the `String teste = "1";`
then it will return true;
Is that a Bug?

I´m working with Android Studio 2.2.2

Here it comes the screenshot of unbelivable unreachable code!
[image]

The break points are marked with an "X" that means it will not be executed for ever!
and the application has paused in the return false statment;!

Comment: I don't believe you. Your assertion cannot possibly be true, or your code isn't what you think it is. Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I copied this code and it returned true. This example is not reproducible. Voting to close.

Comment: did you place any extra space or dot in any of the string by any chance ?

Comment: @nhouser9 What did you used for testing it? I Forgot to mention that this is happening using Android Studio 2.2.2

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri' the string is exactly as is in example!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch please take a look at the screenshot i´ve updated! It´s the example!

Comment: Which version of Java are u using? Also, what happens if you do this: `return "com.br".equals("com.br");`?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQ3VVUVZWZG9WTkk , also move your cursor on 'X' and see the message ti gives

Comment: ```this is happening using Android Studio 2.2.2```: I also tested on Android Studio 2.2.2 and I can't reproduce your issue, code is reachable and returns true.

Comment: Rename the method and clean the code so the .Dex is recreated. Sometimes bugs are in the compiler, assembler and believe it or not The IDEs!

Comment: Build->Clean Project and re-run in the debugger.  I suspect this issue will go away.